# Select from table with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm learning Python programming language todays. today i started work with sqlite in Python. 
i have code like this :

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("test_database.db")

c = connection.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM People")

n = 0
while True :
    row = c.fetchone()
    if row is None :
        break

    n = n + 1

    print(n,"-->",row)

connection.close()
```

and i have a test_database.db with 3 different people information. but my code is printing out like this :

```
1 --> ('Ron', 'Obvious', 42)
2 --> ('Ron', 'Obvious', 42)
3 --> ('Ron', 'Obvious', 42)
[Finished in 0.076s]:
```

My People table is :

```
Ron   Obvious   42
Merdan  Amanow  35
Aman    Meredow 45
```

What must i do to print out my all table?

Comment: Try [fetchall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, I forgot to save db, so the answer was wrong!